# Logitech Joystick Driver and Windows 11 Memory Integrity

Tags: drivers, windows-11, joystick

I was stupid and installed an old Logitech G Extreme 3D Pro Joystick for Windows on a Windows 10 computer that I upgraded to Windows 11. The Logitech drivers are preventing the memory integrity feature from turning on. I can't find a way to uninstall these drivers as they are not in device manager. I've tried restarting to a command prompt but I'm unable to delete them manually. I even file explorer as an administrator and tried renaming the files manually. Nothing seems to get rid of these old files.

[image: Old Joystick Drivers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove them by using the following command

```
pnputil /delete-driver "__".inf /uninstall /force
```

Comment: Should the `"__"` be replaced with the name of the .inf file?

Comment: yes,   eg  oem1.inf

Comment: Thanks so much! If I could send you some cash for solving this problem I would!

Comment: just happy to help!   i just had to deal with this last week.